# How do I resolve type differences when using an EL Resolver with WELD?

Tags: java, jsf, el, cdi, jboss-weld

I have a generic EL producer that I've written to take advantage of WELD's ability to just 'make it work' when I need it done, and even have the type coercion written into the function so that it makes sure the return type matches the weld injection point.

Here's my problem:
WELD resolves from the injection point's assignable types, ie, if your injection point is a String, it will only look for producers with a String return type.

This is problematic, as I want one producer that will take care of the type coercion, and hand back a correctly typed object.

As a kludge, I have a String producer method that aliases to the real producer, and only does the type kludging.

This... at least works, until I get to the situation of having an Object typed injection point, at which point ALL of my kludge methods AND the generic producer ALL are matched, giving an ambiguous dependency exception, even if I use @Typed on the producers.

Is there a sane way around this, or should I give up on this idea of making WELD do all the hard work for me?

Here's an example of the use of this producer, from an error handling bean with a Request scope. RequestURI is the one that is troublesome in this case, the other two require typed "kludge" methods to work.  The main function of this particular bean (code not included) is to catch unhandled exceptions and report them via email to us for more specific error handling in future revisions.  The basic use-case here is to simplify programmatic access to EL, and potentially to allow writing back to EL using the value binding, though that's not possible in this particular code.

I know I can do the below using other methods, that's not the point.  Realistically, it's a positive thing to make it easier to access EL programmatically IMO, especially when dealing with some of the more exotic scopes (especially Flash scope) introduced by JSF 2.0.  Most of my use cases have to do with Flash scope, but aren't safe to disclose here, nor are they predictable types, or types that should have kludges written for them, hence why I want this more generalized method.

```
   @Inject
   @ELResource("#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.exception']}")
   protected Exception exception;

   @Inject
   @ELResource("#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.status_code']}")
   protected String statusCode;

   @Inject
   @ELResource("#{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}")
   protected Object requestUri;
```

Here's my qualifier:

```
@Target(value = {ElementType.FIELD,ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Qualifier
public @interface ELResource {
    @Nonbinding
    String value();
}
```

The producer:

```
@Dependent
public class ELProducer {

    @Inject
    FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    Logger log;

    @Produces
    @ELResource("")
    public Object getELResource(InjectionPoint ip) {
        log.entering(getClass().getName(), "getELResource()",new Object[] {ip});

        ExpressionFactory expFactory = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
        String elString = ip.getAnnotated().getAnnotation(ELResource.class).value();
        Class coercionType = resolveClass(ip);

        log.log(Level.INFO, "EL String: {0} of type: {1}", new Object[] {elString, coercionType.getName()});
        if (elString == null || elString.length() <= 0) {
            log.log(Level.SEVERE,"No EL String specified for injection");
            log.exiting(getClass().getName(), "getELResource()");
            return null;
        }

        ValueExpression ve = expFactory.createValueExpression(facesContext.getELContext(), elString, coercionType);

        if (ve != null) {
            Object retval = ve.getValue(facesContext.getELContext());
            log.log(Level.INFO,"EL Result: {0} of type: {1}",new Object[] { retval, ((retval != null) ? retval.getClass().getName() : "NULL") } );
            log.exiting(getClass().getName(), "getELResource()",new Object[] {retval} );
            return retval;
        } else {
            log.log(Level.WARNING,"Null EL Result");
            log.exiting(getClass().getName(), "getELResource()");
            return null;
        }
    }

    // TODO: There should be a better way of accomplishing the below
    @Produces
    @ELResource("")
    public String getELStringResource(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return (String)getELResource(ip);
    }

    @Produces
    @ELResource("")
    public Exception getELExceptionResource(InjectionPoint ip) {
        return (Exception)getELResource(ip);
    }

    private Class resolveClass(InjectionPoint ip) {
        Annotated annotated = ip.getAnnotated();
        Member member = ip.getMember();

        if (member instanceof Field) {
            Field field = (Field)member;
            return field.getType();
        } else if (member instanceof Constructor) {
            Constructor con = (Constructor)member;
            AnnotatedParameter ap = (AnnotatedParameter)annotated;
            return con.getParameterTypes()[ap.getPosition()];
        } else if (member instanceof Method) {
            Method method = (Method)member;
            AnnotatedParameter ap = (AnnotatedParameter)annotated;
            return method.getParameterTypes()[ap.getPosition()];
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

And the error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [Object] with qualifiers [@ELResource] at injection point [[field] @Inject @ELResource protected xxx.backing.ErrorHandler.requestUri]. Possible dependencies [[Producer Method [Exception] with qualifiers [@Any @ELResource] declared as [[method] @Produces @Typed @ELResource public xxx.ELProducer.getELExceptionResource(InjectionPoint)], Producer Method [String] with qualifiers [@Any @ELResource] declared as [[method] @Produces @Typed @ELResource public xxx.ELProducer.getELStringResource(InjectionPoint)], Producer Method [Object] with qualifiers [@Any @ELResource] declared as [[method] @Produces @Dependent @ELResource public xxx.ELProducer.getELResource(InjectionPoint)]]]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:309)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:139)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:162)
        ...
```

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve? One ore two example usages of EL-Injections would be great.

Answer (score 1):

> I know I can do the below using other
>   methods, that's not the point.

I tried really hard, but I did *not* manage *not* to comment that you are loosing type safety, (which is one of the main design goals of CDI), and that EL evaluation is performance killer ... ;-)

Anyhow, having (*almost not*) said this:

There is no real CDI option to overcome this. What I'd recommend you is to use a specific type for those EL-expressions, like `ElObject` or so, which is constructed by the producer and which itself provides type safe accessors for the client.

**Edit**: You might want to have a look at [Seam Solder](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/solder/latest/reference/en-US/html/elextensions.html), which provides EL-Functionality in a neat way...

Comment: The Seam Solder functionality is extremely close to what I want, just missing the final step that does this automatically at injection time. That may be as close as I can get for now though, so I appreciate the suggestion.